# Unexpected behaviour with GraphIntersection and GraphDifference

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I run into some unexpected behaviour of GraphIntersection and GraphDifference. Behaviour is the same for both so the example is only on the GraphIntersection:

Suppose I have two lists of directed edges, forming a cycle:

> > ```
> > cycle1 = {a \[DirectedEdge] b, b \[DirectedEdge] c, c \[DirectedEdge] d, d \[DirectedEdge] e, e \[DirectedEdge] f, f \[DirectedEdge] g, g \[DirectedEdge] h, h \[DirectedEdge] a};
> >
> > cycle2 = {g \[DirectedEdge] c, c \[DirectedEdge] d, d \[DirectedEdge] e, e \[DirectedEdge] f, f \[DirectedEdge] g};
> > ```

I construct two graphs and I want to select the Intersection between them. This seems to work only for the edges and not for the vertices!

> > ```
> > GraphIntersection[Graph[cycle1], Graph[cycle2]] // EdgeList
> > GraphIntersection[Graph[cycle1], Graph[cycle2]] // VertexList
> > ```
> >
> > (* Out:
> >
> > ```
> > {c \[DirectedEdge] d, d \[DirectedEdge] e, e \[DirectedEdge] f, f \[DirectedEdge] g}
> >
> > {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}
> > ```
> >
> > *)

I would have expected bahaviour identical to the approach of first intersecting the edges and then constructing a graph:

> > ```
> > Graph[Intersection[cycle1, cycle2]] // EdgeList
> >
> > Graph[Intersection[cycle1, cycle2]] // VertexList
> >
> > (* Out:
> > {c \[DirectedEdge] d, d \[DirectedEdge] e, e \[DirectedEdge] f, f \[DirectedEdge] g}
> >
> > {c, d, e, f, g}
> > *)
> > ```

Please note the vertices are correct in the last example, the first example, all vertices are listed.

Could anyone explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [GraphIntersection > Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphIntersection.html):

[image]

Similarly, [GraphDifference > Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphDifference.html)

[image]

In both cases, the vertex set of the graph produced by the two functions is the `Union` of the vertex sets of the input graphs.

Comment: Ah, I read that but only now I realise that this is what it means. Thanks! Do you have any idea what the rationale is behind taking the Union of both the vertex sets vs taking the Intersection? It seems to me redundant somehow...

Comment: @Sander, i don't know why; not familiar enough with graph theory to hazard a guess.